# Script tags embedded in MVC3 Razor views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

First MVC project, just curious what the best way to manage this is.

All of my views that I'm creating contain the following

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I would prefer to keep my js before my closing body tag. I know I can obviously move this to my layout.cshtml file, but I imagine there's a more elegant MVC/Razor way to do this (especially if I have view-specific files that I don't want to load globally).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put my global scripts inside _Layout.cshtml, and then define a [`section`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) for scripts I only want to include from certain views.

E.g. in layout.cshtml

```
<body>
...
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/global1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/global2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@RenderSection("FooterScripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

and then in the views if I need a script I don't want to include globally:

```
@section FooterScripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/local.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Why do we need to specify *false* at all? My intellisense says that there's a *@RenderSection(string)*. Is it something newly added (as I see the post is soon 4 years young)?

Comment: The false parameter here means the section isn't required. It the is no such named section in the view, it will be ignored. The overload without the Boolean parameter behaves as it you had passed true